# Angular URL parameter being removed in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router

I created a path in Angular using Angular's ui-router. Problem is, only in chrome, when I go to:

http://localhost:9000/#/test-app/app/123

Chrome removes my parameter and takes me to http://localhost:9000/#/test-app/app
This does not happen in any other browser. I need to use the parameter in my resolve statement.

I just need the 123 from :id. Chrome doesn't give it to me but safari and firefox do. Chrome does work in incognito mode only.

```
  .state('root.user-by-id', {
    url: 'test-app/app/:id',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: 'DetailViewCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'detail',
    resolve: {
      puzzleById: function($stateParams, userAPI) {
        return userAPI.getUserByID($stateParams.id)
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.state('root.user-by-id', {
   url: '/test-app/app/:id',
```

The slash before the actual routing may be causing the trouble

Comment: No luck, it just shoots me back to the root.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, I initially misread the question.

I'm concerned about your routes not having a preceding "/". I would expect that your url definition would be something along the lines of:

```
url: '/test-app/app/:id'
```

Could you post your similar routes? There's a chance that your client is incorrectly matching to an incorrect/invalid route when trying to evaluate the URL and state.